# Apple watch interface

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I am designing apple watch application where i need to show top10 feed title and i have successfully shown it. in next step i have to add action event to tap which will redirect user to next screen but i am confused which controller to use here. i have to show all feeds in pagination format and then on click i have to show its detail view.

does anyone tried with this approach? i am using UIButton over there but its having text limitation so cant use it and for tableview it scroll verticaly where as i need horizantle scroll.

Comment: You can use simple UIViewController like you do for the app, I guess this is available for the extension, but yes you need to do [self.view addSubview:anothercontroller.view]; and animate like push, instead of pushing in navigationcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

alph0x's answer is pretty useful. But you can also do another thing to perform what you are asking in case you only want that the action will do when push in a specific button of the row.

This second solution consists on create a class for the custom row with an IBAction

```
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>

@interface MyRow : NSObject

// Methods
- (IBAction)buttonClick;

@end
```

And in the buttonClick method, you can specify the action as in the follow example using **pushControllerWithName:context** to go to a specific interface controller

```
#import "MyRow.h"

@implementation MyRow

- (IBAction)buttonClick {
    [self goToInterface:@"feedInterface"];
}

- (void)goToInterface:(NSString *)interfaceName{
    NSDictionary *contextToSend = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"FeedTitle", @"title",
                                   @"lalala", @"secondValue",
                                   @"lelele", @"thirdValue",
                                   @"other value", @"other", nil];

    [self pushControllerWithName:interfaceName context:contextToSend];
}

@end
```

You can send your row info through context. In that example I have decided to send a dictionary with some values.

In the interfaceName param you have to specify the Interface Controller Identifier that you can set in your storyboard. See the image below:
[image]

And tell to the XCode that your table row has the custom class MyRow
[image]

Note: don't forget to assign your button to the IBAction method ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you need to have a table with 10 rows, and you need to be able to tap in one row, and view the details about the one you selected, if thats correct, you only need to use the Method from WKInterfaceTable "- (id)rowControllerAtIndex:(NSInteger)index", with this one (works like UITableView one with the delegate) you can handle every row action after being tapped.